# Configure compile command to take buffer-file-name as its source file argument

Tags: hooks, compile

I am in the way of automating my compilation process with, what is an unexplored but an omnipotent command `compile`. I expect it to decide upon the compiler using the filename extension & also, fill in the file name argument from the current buffer.

I made it half-way through for c & java modes,

```
(defun sk-compile-pre-hook ()
  (pcase major-mode
    ('c-mode
     (setq compile-command (concat "gcc " (buffer-file-name))))
    ('java-mode
     (setq compile-command (concat "javac " (buffer-file-name))))))
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'sk-compile-pre-hook)
(add-hook 'java-mode-hook 'sk-compile-pre-hook)
```

This works as long as I have one file of a type (java or c) open in the buffer. Life is not meant to be easy, though. The moment i open a second file of the same type, the mode hooks are not run again. Possibly, the mode configurations are not loaded the second time.

So, when i invoke compile command from the second file, it still refers to the first file as its argument.

Now, i explored the other way through `advice` as,

```
(advice-add 'compile :before
        (lambda (_)
          (sk-compile-pre-hook)))
```

Now, this puts me one step back, the `compile-command` is not modified and retains its original value as `make -k`.

Is there a work-around to set a new compile command, every time a file is loaded? Something that Vim's `dispatch` plugin provides like 
`autocmd FileType java let b:dispatch = 'javac %'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directory variables may be used to solve the problem.

Contents of `.dir-locals.el` in the root of the project directory:

```
((c-mode . ((eval . 
                     (setq-local compile-command
                                 (concat "gcc " (buffer-file-name))))))
 (java-mode . ((eval . 
                     (setq-local compile-command
                                 (concat "javac " (buffer-file-name)))))))
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html

Use of `eval` in directory or local variables is discussed at https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html

There is a also short example there with `compile-command`.

Comment: this works like a charm. but, a more cleaner solution with one time configuration in .emacs, thus avoiding dir-specific confs is appreciated...

Comment: Try your sk-compile-pre-hook exactly as above except instead of (setq compile-command ...) (setq-local compile-command). If you do C-h o compile-command there is an example making compile-command buffer local in a hook.