# Emacs as Java IDE - How to run code?

Tags: lsp-mode, java, ide

I am looking at setting up Emacs for Java development.
As much as possible, I would like to achieve Emacs being comparable to IntelliJ IDEA in terms of features, and also ease-of-use / "things working automatically".

My question is simply: How do I run java code in Emacs? I ask the question with a range of use-cases in mind:

- Single standalone .java files.
- A program comprised of a bunch of .java files (a package).
  ...
- Full-blown large enterprise-level applications.

Here is some example java code: https://github.com/l0y/learnjava6e (mostly single standalone files, a few package/multi-file programs)
IntelliJ IDEA manages to handle the learnjava6e example code very neatly, you simply have to use the run button and it works. How to get something like that in Emacs?

Some resources I've looked at:
https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-java/ (I have all this setup)
https://xpressrazor.wordpress.com/2020/11/04/java-programming-in-emacs/
Is this a good approach? [Configure compile command to take buffer-file-name as its source file argument](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/80630/configure-compile-command-to-take-buffer-file-name-as-its-source-file-argument)

Comment: you can read this as well, https://cestlaz.github.io/post/using-emacs-74-eglot/